how to force that a generic method never returns a null value
In the following example:
async Task Main()
{
    // data can actually NEVER be null, but here it is of type Response?
    var data1 = GetResponseData();
    var data2 = await GetResponseDataAsync();
}

private Response GetResponseData()
{
    var data = MyHelper("the method", m => GetData<Response>(m));
    return data;
}
private Task<Response> GetResponseDataAsync()
{
    var data = MyHelperAsync("the method", m => GetDataAsync<Response>(m));
    // GIVES NULLABILITY WARNING HERE
    return data;
}
class Response
{
    public int prop { get; set; }
}

TResp? GetData<TResp>(string method)
{
    return default(TResp);
}

TResp MyHelper<TResp>(string method, Func<string, TResp> getData)
{
    var data = getData(method);
    if (data is null)
        throw new Exception("data should not be null");
        
    return data;
}

in the main method the data variable is nullable, except that in reality it can never be null, and I'd like to force that knowledge.
I dont want to modify the GetData method as it CAN return null
[Edit]
The solution also seems to work in the async case (surprisingly!):
eg:
async Task Main()
{
    var data2 = await MyHelperAsync("the method", m => GetDataAsync<Response>(m));
    
    data2.prop.Dump();
}

class Response
{
    public int prop { get; set; }
}

Task<TResp?> GetDataAsync<TResp>(string method)
{
    return Task.FromResult(default(TResp));
}

[return: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.NotNull]
async Task<TResp> MyHelperAsync<TResp>(string method, Func<string, Task<TResp>> getData)
{
    var data = await getData(method);
    if (data is null)
        throw new Exception("data should not be null");

    return data;
}



in the main method the data variable is nullable, except that in reality it can never be null, and I'd like to force that knowledge.

This is the sort of thing that the additional nullable attributes help with. In this case you want NotNull applied to the return value:
[return:NotNull]
TResp MyHelper<TResp>(string method, Func<string, TResp> getData)

In a quick test, Visual Studio still shows the inferred type of data as Response? in Intellisense when you use var, but it "knows" that it's not null (you can call data.ToString() with no warnings for example) and you don't get any warnings if you explicitly specify the type of data as Response (whereas you would have done before). (This may be an Intellisense issue more than anything else.)

How do you verify what the compiler thinks in terms of var? I use JetBrains Rider, and hovering over the var keyword just shows Response, and using refactoring replaces it with Response (which then Rider wants to turn back into var). Just curious how to verify this myself.

@LasseV.Karlsen: I was hovering over the declaration in VS. But "make explicit" changes it to Response, which is weird. Will edit...

Actually, I just now discovered that hovering over var in Rider shows Response and hovering over data shows Response?. It still uses Response as specific type, though.

what can I do if actually these are async methods, and GetDataAsync returns Task<TResp?>
Interestingly, it looks like the return:NotNull annotaton works with Task to apply it the TResp rather than to the Task
So, all ok

Are you sure all is then OK, with the introduction of Task<T> I mean? Rider at least then complains that data is possiblynull, if I dovar data = await MyHelper...`. However, I believe there is another attribute you can then use, let me see if I can dig it out before Jon Skeet beats me.

Mmm, in my specific code (not just my example), I've added the annotation to the Task returning helper method, and the compiler (or Resharper?) is saying "The nullability attribute has no effect and can be safely removed", and it doesnt help remove warnings!

I'm not sure it is OK now, altho the example code did seem OK in LinqPad (eg hovering over the var gives "Response")

Upon investigation, it seems you can't specify this. The compiler can use NullableContext and Nullable to specify that Task<..> can be nullable, but the <T> of Task<T> will not, but those attributes are not legal in user-code.

Maybe you can do this instead: Task<TResp> MyHelper<TResp>(string method, Func<string, TResp?> getData) where TResp : notnull, although something is nagging the back of my brain about it. Nope, that doesn't work either if your method can use both structs and classes, you would have to do where TResp : class, notnull

The way to tell is if you get a warning when you encapsulate the method calls currently in main into some methods that return Response/Task.  The non-async version seems OK, but the Task returning method gives a nullability warning still

I think the conclusion is that this cant be solved for the Task<> case.
